# Issue with understanding numpy array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-indexing

When slicing a Numpy array, it looks inconsistent to me.

```py
In[87]: y
Out[87]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In[88]: y[0,0]
Out[88]: 1
```

`y[0,0]` is `1`. That's OK, but when I type

```py
In[89]: y[0,0:1]
Out[89]: array([1])
```

Why is the slice `[0,0:1]` the single value array `[1]`? I was rather expecting `array[1,4]` which occurs when I type

```py
In[90]: y[0,0:2]
Out[90]: array([1,4])
```

where I'd rather expect `array[1,4,7]` since `y[0,2]` is `7`.

By the way, if of importance, I'm using Anaconda 2019 distro.

```py
In[91]: import sys
   ...: print(sys.version)
3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Has anyone a clue why the slicing indexes look so confusing  ?
Thanks

Comment: This same pattern occurs when slicing strings and lists: `abcde'[0:2]` and `[0,1,2,3,4][0:2]`.  And ranges: `list(range(2))` and `np.arange(0,2)`.  All produce a result that is 2 items long.

Comment: Slicing in Python is generally for a half open interval. So [0:1] is 0 to 1 EXCLUDING 1 so 0 only.  Similarly [0:2 ] is 0 to 2 excluding 2 so 0, 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy uses the same slicing notation as Python does, i.e. `[start:stop:step]`.

As a convention, the value at index `stop` is excluded from the resulting sequence.

You can find more information at paragraph 3 of [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/index-slice-reshape-numpy-arrays-machine-learning-python/).

> The slice extends from the ‘from’ index and ends one item before the ‘to’ index.

Comment: Thanks Jacques. Even if it seems a bit odd, I take as it is. This closes satisfactorily the subject for me. Cheers.